# Specify endpoint for getting OAuth token in java for LinkedIn

Tags: wso2, linkedin-api, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB to proxy LinkedIn service . How can i specify the endpoint in java while fetching the access token using Scribe ? The current end point is https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize but i want it to change it to the address of my ESB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer ! The endpoints can be changed in the file

> LinkedInApi.java

in `/src/main/java/org/scribe/builder/api` folder.